# htaccess 301 redirect to home page

Tags: .htaccess

I need the solution for home page 301 redirection.

If I enter like below url in the browse bar

`http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/tilfoj-din-butik/city/86-morso?sem_midx=0&sem_jidx=6`

`http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/component/user/reset?sem_midx=12&sem_jidx=-6`

`http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/restaurants-in-denmark/restaurant/1-frederiks-have?sem_midx=-1&sem_jidx=-10`

then it will be redirected to `http://www.starmed.dk` without index.php

Any idea how to do this with an HTACCESS 301 redirect for above 3 url to common code?

Thanks in advance.

### Edited Code:

I'm using below code.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(forside?start=5|tilfoj-din-butik/city/68-middelfart?sem_midx=5&sem_jidx=1|tilfoj-din-butik/city/86-morso?sem_midx=0&sem_jidx=6|restaurants-in-denmark/restaurant/1-frederiks-have?sem_midx=-1&sem_jidx=-10|tilfoj-din-butik/city/92-greve?sem_midx=-1&sem_jidx=1|component/user/register|component/restaurantguide/restaurant/4-bybuens-smorrebrod?sem_midx=-4&sem_jidx=0|restaurants-in-denmark/restaurant/1-frederiks-have?sem_midx=2&sem_jidx=12|tilfoj-din-butik/tags/12-fuldkorn|component/restaurantguide/restaurant/6-cafe-konjak?sem_midx=-1&sem_jidx=0|tetest/city/18-helsingorst|about-us/restaurant/14-mevlana-kulgrill|tilfoj-din-butik/restaurant/1-dilans-pizza?sem_midx=0&sem_jidx=0|component/user/reset?sem_midx=12&sem_jidx=-6|component/restaurantguide/tags/tags/3-udbringning?sem_midx=1&sem_jidx=3|restaurants-in-denmark/restaurant/1-dilans-pizza?sem_midx=2&sem_jidx=4|component/restaurantguide/restaurant/1-frederiks-have?sem_midx=4&sem_jidx=0|component/restaurantguide/testimonial/1-excellent-restaurant?sem_midx=1&sem_jidx=4|takeaway/tags/5-grill) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
```

Some condition is working. But some condition is not working.
Not working url
`http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/component/restaurantguide/restaurant/6-cafe-konjak?sem_midx=-1&sem_jidx=0`

`http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/restaurants-in-denmark/restaurant/1-frederiks-have?sem_midx=2&sem_jidx=12`

Edited Code 1:

these below url only not working.

http://www.starmed.dk/?option=com_restaurantguide&view=states&id=450:midtjylland

http://www.starmed.dk/?index%5c.php%25253Fid=3-yorkshire-savings-account.83&xzaty=3&article=83

How Can I do rule for above 2 url?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a single rule:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(tilfoj-din-butik/city/86-morso\?sem_midx=0&sem_jidx=6|component/user/reset\?sem_midx=12&sem_jidx=-6|restaurants-in-denmark/restaurant/1-frederiks-have\?sem_midx=-1&sem_jidx=-10) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Its working fine. But could you please send common single code for above 3 url?

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/tilfoj-din-butik/city/86-morso\?sem_midx=0&sem_jidx=6 [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/component/user/reset\?sem_midx=12&sem_jidx=-6 [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/restaurants-in-denmark/restaurant/1-frederiks-have\?sem_midx=-1&sem_jidx=-10  [NC]

these above 3 url, you can make it single rule?

Comment: yes, you are right, can you make single condition with single rule?

Comment: Rule you've shown is not the rule I've provided in my answer. In general you must escape `?` and avoid changing requirements via comments.

Comment: Because your rule condition doesn't handle `option=com_restaurantguide&view=states&id=450:midtjylland`